# How to get list of all published pages with CD API?

Tags: web8, content-delivery, web8.5

Do you know if there is any way to get list of all published pages for specific publication by using Content Delivery API?

Something similar to next API, but for pages:

```
new PublicationMetaFactory().getAllMeta();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the working code example for getting the published pages items:

```
    int publicationId = 8; //change this value to your publicationId on your environment   
    PublicationCriteria publicationCiteria = new PublicationCriteria(publicationId);
    ItemTypeCriteria itemCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(64);
    Query query = new Query(CriteriaFactory.And(new Criteria[] { publicationCiteria, itemCriteria }));
    SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ItemLastPublishedDate, SortParameter.Descending);
    query.AddSorting(sortParameter);
    string[] itemIds = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Right, we need to use Query object. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tested this, but I would probably use a `Query` object with its `Criteria` property set accordingly.

Meaning:

- `PublicationCriteria` to select the desired publication
- `ItemTypeCriteria` to select only pages.

Make sure to `"And"` these two criteria together. Once you have the criteria, you would simply call `ExecuteQuery` on the `Query` object and it will return the list of `Tcm`-s. Since this is the CD we're talking about, you will only get the Items present there, in other words, only the published ones.